# iOS stream cutting long messages in the middle

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a little function to speak with my Nodejs server:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {
    NSLog(@"stream event %i", streamEvent);

    switch (streamEvent) {

        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            NSLog(@"Stream opened");
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

            if (theStream == inputStream) {
                uint8_t buffer[1024];
                int len;

                while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                    if (len > 0) {


                        NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                        if (nil != output) {

                            // Parse the message and add it to the right method
                            NSError* error;
                            NSDictionary *JSON =
                            [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [output dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                            options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                              error: &error];

                            NSString* type = [JSON objectForKey:@"type"];

                            NSLog(@"SERVER TYPE: %@\n", type);
                            NSLog(@"SERVER SENT: %@\n", output);

                            if([type isEqualToString:@"visitorLoad"]) {
                                NSLog(@"New visitor load: %@", output);
                                [self visitorReceived:output];

                            } else if([type isEqualToString:@"message"]) {
                                NSLog(@"New chat message: %@", output);

                                [self messageReceived:output];

                            } else if([type isEqualToString:@"offlineMessages"]) {
                                //NSLog(@"New offline messages: %@", output);
                                NSLog(@"NEW OFFLINE MESSAGES!!");
                                [self offlineMessagesReceived:output];

                            } else if([type isEqualToString:@"agentMsg"]) {
                                NSLog(@"New AGENT MESSAGE: %@", output);

                                [self agentMessageReceived:output];

                            } else if([type isEqualToString:@"heartbeat"]) {
                                // Take no action
                                NSLog(@"Heartbeat recieved");

                            } else if([type isEqualToString:@"visitorExit"]) {

                                [self visitorHasGoneOffline:output];

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;


        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:

            NSLog(@"Can not connect to the host!");
            isConnected = 0;
            //[self initNetworkCommunication];
            break;

        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:

            [theStream close];
            [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            //[theStream release];
            NSLog(@"STREAM PAUSED");
            theStream = nil;

            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Unknown event");
    }

}
```

The problem is that when Im sending large JSON messaged from my node server the above cuts it into multiple parts, making it unable for me to parse.

This is how i open the stream:

```
// Open connection to server
- (void)initNetworkCommunication {
    isConnected = TRUE;
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"server.com", 8080, &readStream, &writeStream);
    inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];

    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];

    [self openDB];
    [self createTable];
}
```

Any ideas what could be causing this? Im 100% certain the message is being sent correctly from my servern. The problem only appears when the message is large with lots of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you have it. Try

```
    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

uint8_t buffer[1024];
int len;
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
   len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
   if (len > 0) {
       [data appendBytes:buffer length:len];
   }
}


NSError* error;
NSDictionary *JSON =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
```

Comment: Getting error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMutableData dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa045a70'`

Comment: Ive edited the post above and removed the & sign before the buffer. Please try again.

Comment: Getting this: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMutableData dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa00fc50'`

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with NSURLConnection. Large data seemed to be chopped in half, resulting in the JSON conversion producing NULL.

Maybe you should merge all data in

```
case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable
   NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   wholeString  = [wholeString stringByAppendString:output];
```

And then convert to JSON in

```
    case NSStreamEventEndEncountered
       NSDictionary *JSON =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [wholeString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                  error: &error];
       ...
```

Good luck!

Comment: No luck with that unfortunately :(

Comment: Oh and this is exactly my problem, that stream is being chopped and JSON conversion is producing NULL.

Comment: Its called once, but the data is being chopped anyway

Comment: The `while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable])` is called as many times as the data is being chopped however

Comment: I upped `uint8_t buffer[5000000];` it seems to work!

Comment: Try my answer below instead. A more memory efficient approach